# Compatibility between Visual Source Safe and Visual Team Foundation

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I have a Visual Source Safe 6.0 server and my client version is VSS 2005. Everything is going fine in this scenario. Now I want to purchase new licenses of Visual Source Safe but VSS is currently obsolete. So I have to purchase Visual Team Foundation to server my purpose.

My question is, do I need to change my existing server for Visual Team Foundation or I can still use my existing server?

Comment: This is off topic here... Luckily for you, I wanted to flag it but pressed the wrong button. Anyway, you might be able to get VSS through an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

VSS and TFS are not compatible. You will need to update both the client and server components. Read [the guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181247(v=vs.90).aspx) to learn more details on how to migrate from VSS to TFS.